# Can I exclude Migrations folder in TFS Source <Control Explorer

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I have a solution where i use Entity Framework and code first.
I have made a few add-migration and update-database, so I got an Migrations folder.

In Source Control Explorer I want to make a branch of my project but it also copies the Migrations folder. Is therer a way to exclude the Migrations folder so that it does not get in the branch.

Because if I do it with Migrations i get an error in the new branch on running it.

Nothing, I could not find anywhere to exclude the folder.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Regardless, I don't think the migrations are the problem, the *error* is the problem. What is the error and what steps are you taking to resolve it? You shouldn't be trying to exclude migrations, you should be fixing the problem with running them.